# Cocos2d-iphone : Handle Button Press and Release

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Actually I need to move my sprite as long as button is pressed and the sprite should be stopped when button is released.

My code is below:

```
 CCMenuItemFont *item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString: @"icon.png" target:self selector:@selector(doit)];
        CCMenu * taskMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item1,  nil];
        [self addChild:taskMenu];

-void()doit
{
        spritevelocity = 80;
}
```

The above code makes my sprite keep on moving when the button is tapped, but I need to stop my sprite as soon as button is released.

I tried below code but no success:

```
-void()doit
{
    buttonpressed = YES;
    if (buttonpressed) {
        spritevelocity = 80;
    }
}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
         buttonpressed = NO;
}
```

Note:I just wanted to make spritevelocity = 0 to stop my sprite,,That is i want spritevelocity = 0 when button is released

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile.

Comment: How can we work with an example that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass CCMenuItem in case to override `selected`, `unselected` and `activate` methods. there, you can force you button to act as you whant to. In this case, act not only on press, but on release too. Here is a good example of overriding CCMenu: http://johnehartzog.com/2009/10/easy-to-create-buttons-with-cocos2d/

Comment: hello sentinel,, my button works fine...but the sprite keeps on moving when button is tapped .It is not stopping even after release,i want to stop when button is released

Comment: to do this, you need to catch button release moment. to do this, you need subclass button.

Comment: I cannot understand that example sentinel...can i get another example

Comment: as @SentineL sais, subclass the type of button you want. Also override the 'unselected' method. Your class will be served a callback to that method when the button becomes unselected for any reason (finger off, finger slides off label, finger slides off screen). In that method, set the sprite velocity to 0.

Comment: Sorry, I have no more examples. In my project I used that one. Hope, YvesLeBrog's post makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the velocity directly?

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     buttonpressed = NO;
     spritevelocity = 0;
 }
```

Could you explain when is `doIt` called?

Comment: Yea i tried it but it works when i touch somewhere else on screen , but not when i press and release CCMenu button.

Comment: check CCMenuItemFont *item1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString: @"icon.png" target:self selector:@selector(doit)]; ,,

Comment: I oversaw that, sorry... I think that @SentineL gave you the right answer... you need to override the standard behavior of cocos2d buttons to handle the "touchUp" event...